# Serving static files from root directory in Django

Tags: python, django

I have app level static files and want to serve global static files such as JQuery, my project structure is like this:

```
mysite
├───dashboard
│   ├───migrations
│   ├───static
│   │   └───dashboard
│   │       ├───css
│   │       ├───img
│   │       └───js
│   └───templates
│       └───dashboard
├───etc
├───static
│   └───js
|       └───jquery.min.js
└───mysite
```

I added the followed the django docs so that the settings.py looks

```
STATIC_ROOT = ""

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIR = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    os.path.join("static"),
]

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]
```

my urls.py looks like this

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("", include(dashboard.urls)),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

my INSTALLED_APPS looks like this

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    "dashboard",
]
```

when I try to access it from a template, it returns a response code 404 in the runserver log,

```
[09/Apr/2020 01:59:34] "GET /static/js/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1674
```

the template tag is like this

```
{% load static %}
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
```

This is my first Django project without following a tutorial, and any help would be appreciated. Thank You

EDIT: I was able to solve the problem by removing the `STATIC_ROOT` setting

Comment: Please show INSTALLED_APPS and urls.py

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a prefix in front of one of the two directories named `static` because Django will use the first static file it finds whose name matches, and if you had a static file with the same name in a different application, Django would be unable to distinguish between them. We need to be able to point Django at the right one, and the best way to ensure this is by `namespacing` them. That is, by putting those static files inside another directory named for the application itself.

You can namespace static assets in STATICFILES_DIRS by specifying [prefixes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs-prefixes). For example:

```
STATICFILES_DIR = [
    ("main", os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")),
    os.path.join("static"),
]
```

and then:

```
<script src="{% static 'main/js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
```

Comment: Use STATICFILES_DIRS instead STATICFILES_DIR